# CPT Post Permalink on Wordpress admin redirecting to admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am having an issue with a custom Post Type that I registered that on the admin single post page while the URL looks like this:

http://devsite.loc/group_opportunity/fdfdf/

When I click on it it takes me back to the same page i.e. here:

http://mysite.loc/wp-admin/post.php?post=375209&action=edit

This is not my desired functionality - I would like it to be like the Wordpress Post pages which take you to the front-end post.

**What I've tried**

1) I have made sure that the post was published (it is) and that I can access the front end link (I can).

2) I've tried adjusting the re-write rules e.g.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
```

including setting them to false, setting them to true, changing 'with_front' to true and false.

In each case I've used:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

TIA,

Laura

**Edit:** I actually think this is something to do with capabilities, because if I don't add capabilities when registering my post I don't have the issue. Will see if I can debug WP Core and revert.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was simple.

You need the member to have a 'read' capability for the link to redirect to the front end.

Because I was mapping my meta capabilities to primitive capabilities manually I was mapping 'read_post' to 'read_group_opportunities' - which my user didn't have.

I should instead have been mapping to 'read'. I sorted that and now works.